# Prolog recrusive Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, prolog

```
foo(0,Y,Z) :- Z is Y.
foo(X,0,Z) :- Z is X.
foo(X,Y,Z) :- X>=Y, M1 is X-2, foo(M1, Y, Zx), Z is Zx + Y.
foo(X,Y,Z) :- Y<X, N1 is Y-3, foo(X, N1, Zx), Z is Zx + X.
```

So this is my program and this is what i'm trying to accomplish

(, ) = 
{

≤ 0

≤ 0

+ ( − 2, )   ≥

+ (,  − 3)   < 
}

Why does my program not output anything? 
This is what i think i'm saying -

If X = 0, foo(0,Y,Z), than return Z as Y.
If Y = 0, foo(0,Y,Z), than return Z as X.

if X>=Y, than do foo again and once that returns than return Z as Zx + Y
if X

Am i correct in my thinking?

Comment: What is bothering me a little bit about the definition you are showing, is that the 4 possibilities are not mutually exclusive (only the two last ones are). You are not saying how to read this: do you commit to the first that matches, or can _foo()_ you have multiple return values for the same arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in your function is

```
   ≤ 0
   ≤ 0
```

that is "**less** **or** equal to zero" not "equal to zero".

So I suppose that

```
foo(0,Y,Z) :- Z is Y.
```

should be

```
foo(X, Y, Y) :- X =< 0.
```

and that

```
foo(X,0,Z) :- Z is X.
```

should be

```
foo(X, Y, X) :- Y =< 0.
```

Comment: Ok so, I did those changes, but i still don't output anything... just a 'no'

Comment: @TravisDelly You should show how you run the program. Works for me.

Comment: @TravisDelly - which input values are you trying? And what do you expects as output?

Comment: I expect an output of Z = 18 for (5,6,Z)

Comment: @TravisDelly I get: `?- foo(5,6,Z). Z = 18.`

Comment: huh... IDk why i'm not gettin any output... This language makes me want to smack my head.