# Function in prolog with backtracking

Tags: prolog, predicate, backtracking

The function is

[backtracking function f(n,k)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apjzf.png)

or

```
f(n, k) = n * k,           if n = k
        = n ∗ f(n−1, k),   if n > k
        = k ∗ f(n,   k−1), if n < k
```

The Prolog predicate `fn/3` assign in order to implement the above function

Can you help me solve the above function?
Thank you

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40920830/1812457) for an example of how to ask, and an idea how to solve it yourself.

Comment: What you have tried, at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the below predicates.

```
f(N, K, R):-
    N = K ,
    R is N*K,!.

f(N, K, R):-
    N>K,
    Nx is N-1,
    f(Nx,K,Res),
    R is N*Res.

f(N, K, R):-
    N<K,
    Kx is K-1,
    f(N,Kx,Res),
    R is K * Res.
```

The R will have the result that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great